# Is it possible to sell a commercial android app using OpenCV android port?

Tags: android, open-source, opencv, augmented-reality

I'm interested in developing an android app that makes use of an `OpenCV` android port at http://code.google.com/p/android-opencv/. Particularly, I want to use `SURF` features which comes embedded in the `OpenCV` framework but I'm not sure if then I will be able to sell this app.

Anyway, is there any non-free app making use of any of the `OpenCV` android ports?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for legal advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SURF is a patented algorithm. You need permissions to use it in commercial applications. SURF comes with OpenCV because there its being used for "academic" or "research" purposes, without any commercialization involved.

Answer (score 0):

Read the license files of the particular port you are using.

The two different ports I googled and looked at in the past two minutes seem quite clear.